# Observable contains array of ID to call another observable

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, observable

I have a data structure in firebase

```
{
    "name": "Sample",
    "category": ["123456", "789012"] 
}
```

The array of category contains ID which refers to documents in another collection. I can get the above document as Observable. What I really what as the end result is the below data structure

```
{
    "name": "Sample"
    "category": [
         {
           "name": "Category 1"
         },
         {
           "name": "Category 2"
         }
    ]
}
```

How can I bring this data? I don't think switchMap works for this. If so, can someone give an example of that?

Comment: You can try and use "flatMap" on the observable for the first query. Flat map is like a Promises "then" function. It allows you to chain multiple async requests together.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any snippet for the solution you gave?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [flatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) and [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html). FlatMap allows you to chain multiple async requests together and forkJoin allows you to wait for all observables to return a value before continuing.

And you could wright something like this:

```
var finalData;
firstRequest('sample').flatMap((data) => {
    // assuming data = { name: "Sample", catagory: [ "23123", "31321", ... ] }
    finalData = data;
    var observables = [];
    data.catagory.forEach((c) => {
        observable.push(secondRequest(c));
    });
    return forkJoin(observables);
}).flatMap((results) => {
    // assuming results is an array like [ { name: "Catagory 1", ... } ]
    finalData.category = results;
    return finalData;
});
```